# Delay Autoplay in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, autoplay, dvdfab

The question is, how do you delay AutoPlay in Windows 7? (Below is the reason and the scenario)

I am using DVD Fab 8.0.8.5 to decrypt movies (that I own) into the raw Video TS and Audio TS folders so that I can then convert them to mp4 files for streaming and mobile entertainment with my IPod.

I have DVD Fab set as the default program for DVDs in the Control Panel -> AutoPlay section (as seen below).

[image: Screenshot]

When AutoPlay tries to start DVD Fab, like it is supposed to, I get the following error.

[image]

I can then proceed to click "OK" in the pop up, start DVD Fab manually (Ugh... manual...), and everything works as it is supposed to. Is there anyway to delay AutoPlay? I think that is the issue, it is going too fast and cannot see the D:\ before it is recognized. If it is another issue, please tell me. I have Google-ed this for a while with no results.

Comment: From a security perspective, Autoplay is best left disabled entirely.  But, I'm sure that's not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Does not make any sense to me, Autoplay starts when it recognizes the medium. At that point it has a path already..

Comment: I don't understand it either @soandos...

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a bit of a stab in the dark here.  Take this as guidance, not a solution.

Open the *Registry Editor* and navigate to:

```
\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DVD\shell\play\command
```

Here is the command that executes *DVD Fab* when you insert a DVD.  I'm assuming it resembles something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\DVDFab\DVDFab.exe" "%L"
```

The "%L" stands for "drive letter", in this case "D:".  *DVD Fab* expects more details.  Take a look at the [DVD Fab Command Line reference](http://www.dvdfab.com/manual/introduction/command-line).  Try:

```
"C:\Program Files\DVDFab\DVDFab.exe" /MODE "FULLDISC" /SRC "%L\VIDEO_TS"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer @Han-E-Food! +1, I will accept it if it works. Sorry I have not had enough time to check to see if this works yet. (I haven't even had time when at home to start that computer up... lol)

Comment: This did not fix it unfortunately... But, I am still playing around with this idea and some of the tools you have given me. Thank you very much!